# How to create a column in table where the value come from the summation of another column in another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have 2 tables in PowerBI.

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2:**

[image]

I have the sales target for each month in Table 1 and also the actual sales that I achieved in Table 2. May I know how should I create another column in Table 1 where it sum all the sales from Table 2 based on respective months? The expected output will be something like this:

**Expected output:**

[image]

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In powerquery: Actual Sales: `Group By month/Year` and `aggregate` with Sum of Sales.  Then `Join` the two tables based on the `Month/Year` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one potential solution:

1. Summarize table two so that it groups the total sales by month. You can do this by grouping on the month in power query, or using a dax function like SUMMARIZE.
2. Create your new column in table 1 using the LOOKUPVALUE function. It will look something like this LOOKUPVALUE(Total Sales, Date, Month & Yrs).

Comment: I tried to use `Group By` in power query, but i received this error message: `Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Text and Text.
Details:
    Operator=-
    Left=Sep 2021
    Right=Sep 2021`

Comment: Is the Month Column of date type before you group?

Answer (score 0):

Make a relationship between Table 1 and Table 2 using "Month & Yrs" and "Date".

Then it's just a matter of adding a table with "Month & Yrs" as rows, and "Sales Target" and "Sales" as values. You can then just rename if you want.

I'd recommend using a calendar dimension as a general rule. Much easier to make relationships, add columns etc.

Comment: How should I add a table with those values inside? Since the values come from 2 different tables

Comment: That's what the relationship is for. It'll link the data.